# Finding complexity of my Code

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the question the following question taken from leetcode(https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/)

Given an unsorted integer array, find the first missing positive integer.

For example,
Given [1,2,0] return 3,
and [3,4,-1,1] return 2.

Your algorithm should run in O(n) time and uses constant space.

```
class Solution(object):
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            while nums[i] != i+1:
                if nums[i]<=0 or nums[i]>len(nums) or nums[i]==nums[nums[i]-1]:
                    break
                else:
                    temp=nums[nums[i]-1]
                    nums[nums[i]-1]=nums[i]
                    nums[i]=temp
        for i in range(len(nums)):
           if nums[i]!=i+1:
               return i+1
        return len(nums)+1
b=Solution()
print b.firstMissingPositive([1,1])
```

I am sure this solution has has complexity of O(n^2). But still many online solutions have used same algorithm.

Can anyone explain how this code has O(n) complexity

Comment: This seems to be O(n^2), are you sure it's the same algorithm?

Comment: It's hard to tell at a glance what this code's complexity is, because the `while` loop doesn't have a well-defined number of iterations. It's possible that it has an O(1) amortized time, in which case the whole code is O(N). I'm not saying that's necessarily the case; just that you can't discard the possibility off-handedly.

Comment: Yes you are right @Kevin. But in worst case my complexity is O(n^2) for case [4,1,2,3]

Comment: @Untitled123  http://codingmelon.com/2015/12/27/first-missing-positive-leetcode-41/
https://tianrunhe.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/finding-the-1st-missing-positive-int-in-an-array-first-missing-positive/

Comment: please fix the indentation on your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is indeed `O(n)`.

First, note that the if clause in the main loop is happening at most `n` times (at most once per value of `i`).

In addition, the `else` clause is also happening `O(n)` times, since if a value is already in its position, you never change its location again (guaranteed from the if condition).

Thus, in the main loop, there are at most `n` entries to the `if` clause, and at most `n` entries to the `else` clause, giving us total run time of `O(n)` for this loop.

The second loop (which is not nested in the first one), is `O(n)` as well, so total complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: in case of input [4,1,2,3] my code when it enters the first loop it it will start swapping and after first iteration array would become[1,2,3,4] after the while loop has run 3 times and after this outer loop would still go forward 3 times and check if all values are at correct position.

Comment: @MridulBirla After first iteration, the array is sorted, and thus any following iterations you are going to have: `nums[2] == 3` and thus: `nums[nums[2]-1] == nums[3-1] == nums[2] == 3` (and similarly for all `i != 0`), and the `while` loop breaks immidiately, in O(1) time. So you basically have in your example first iteration of for loop is O(n), next `n-1` iterations are O(1) each, giving you `O(n + n*1) = O(n)` total.